# How to iterate over a List containing array of strings

Tags: java, list, foreach, iterator

I am reading csv file with openCSV reader. There is a method readAll which gives List as the result.

```
List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
```

I want to get the each string from it. I tried this, but doesn't worked out.

```
Iterator itr = myEntries.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Object element = itr.next();
    for(String temp:element)
       System.out.println(temp);
}
```

It's giving me an error saying, `foreach` cannot be applied to type `Object`. How to get the strings from it?

Comment: Why is `element` an `Object` instead of a `String[]`?

Comment: Type casting is not used properly in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a way to solve it is not important for you, I suggest using `foreach` statements:

```
for(String[] a : myEntries)
    for(String s : a) 
        // do what you want to
```

Otherwise, you should write like

```
Iterator<String[]> iterator = myEntries.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
    for(String temp : itr.next()) 
        // Don't worry, itr.next() will be created only one time
        // for an each iteration (while)
        System.out.println(temp);
```

, that looks not pretty and may have difficulty in reading.

Comment: The second one is not working, it says Foreach is not applicable on type object

Comment: @LokeshS, don't use a raw type of iterator, I corrected

Answer (score 2):

The list elements are of type `String[]`. Use this in the declaration:

```
Iterator<String[]> itr = myEntries.iterator();

...

String[] element = itr.next();
```

Comment: No, it's not working saying Required: Java.lang.String[] Found: Java.lang.Object. I am surprised.... I expected required: object, but found: String[]

Comment: Yes, the iterator needs to be correctly typed as well. See update

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code,

```
for (String[] element : myEntries) {
    for (String temp : element)
        System.out.println(temp);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.readAll().forEach(stringArray -> {
   for(String element : stringArray){
      System.out.println(element);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a foreach loop, just like you did for the array:

```
for (String[] entry : myEntries) {
    for (String temp : element) {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

If you really need an Iterator, then don't use a raw type:

```
for (Iterator<String[]> it = myEntries.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String[] entry = it.next();
    for (String temp : entry) {
         System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

You should always use curly braces around blocks, even if your block has a single instruction. That makes the code more readable, more maintainable, and helps avoiding many bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer Java 8, its every more declarative.

```
myEntries.forEach(entries -> 
    Arrays.stream(entries).forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry)));
```